# Number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+\dots +x_n=r$ via evaluation of Cauchy's integral

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am not sure if this is duplicate. Here I have a problem of using Cauchy's integral. The number of solutions $(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_s)$ that $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_s=n$ by using
$$F(s) = \sum_{m\ge 0} z^{m};|z|<1.$$
We obtain $$F(z)^s=\sum_{m_1,m_2,\dots,m_s\ge 0}z^{m_1+m_2+\dots +m_s}=\sum_{n\ge0}R_s(n)z^n,$$
where $R_s(n)$ is the number of partitions $n$ into $s$ nonnegative parts. We then have
$$R_s(n)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{0<|z|<1} \dfrac{F(z)^s}{z^{n+1}}dz.$$
I calculate the integral like this
$$\int_{|z|}\dfrac{F(z)^s}{z^{n+1}}dz=\int_{|z|}\dfrac{1/(1-z)^s}{z^{n+1}}dz=\dfrac{2\pi i}{n!}\cdot\dfrac{d^n}{dz^n}\left(\dfrac{1}{(1-z)^s}\right)\Big|_{z=0}$$
We have that $\dfrac{d^n}{dz^n}\dfrac{1}{(1-z)^s}=\dfrac{s(s+1)\cdots (s+n-1)}{(1-z)^{s+n}}$ so that the right part is $2\pi i\cdot s(s+1)\cdots (s+n-1)/n!$ and $$R_s(n)=\dfrac{(n+s-1)!}{n!(s-1)!}=\binom{n+s-1}{n}.$$
Am I right using Cauchy's integral and residue? I am new to complex analysis.

Comment: Looks correct to me, and your answer agrees with the stars-and-bars solution.